# Displaying Loading Indicator in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

How can we programmatically display the `page loading` indicator in JQuery Mobile?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$.mobile.loading("show");
$.mobile.loading("hide");
```

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/methods.html